# Is it possible to use a concrete implementation, and Refit, to implement the same service in a Blazor Web App?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, refit

I'm building a Blazor Web App. I have identified that some pages and components need access to some external data, and I have defined an interface that allows them to access these data.

```csharp
public interface IHelloWorld
{
  Task<string> GetHelloWorldAsync();
}
```

In the Blazor Server part of the web app, I want to use a concrete implementation of IHelloWorld which fetches data from the appropriate source.

```csharp
public class HelloWorld
{
  public Task<string> GetHelloWorldAsync()
  {
    return Task.FromResult("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

I also want to be able to retrieve these data from the WASM part of the web app, and rather than exposing database servers directly to the internet I want to send requests via a controller in the Blazor Server part. I've written a controller...

```csharp
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
{
  private IHelloWorld _helloWorld;

  public HelloWorldController(IHelloWorld helloWorld)
  {
    _helloWorld=helloWorld;
  }
  [HttpGet("HelloWorld")]
  public Task<IActionResult> GetHelloWorld()
  {
    return Ok(await _helloWorld.GetHelloWorldAsync());
  }
}
```

... and a client, using Refit...

```csharp
public interface IHelloWorldClient
{
  [Get("/api/HelloWorld/HelloWorld"])
  Task<string> GetHelloWorld();
}
```

In my Razor component, I can inject an IHelloWorld and use this with server side rendering just fine.

```csharp
@inject IHelloWorld HelloWorld

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_greeting)){
  <p>@_greeting</p>
}

@code{
 private string _greeting;
 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
    var helloWorld = HelloWorld.GetHelloWorldAsync();
 }
}
```

However, this component cannot run client side because there is no suitable concrete implementation of IHelloWorld. I could inject IHelloWorldClient instead, but then the server side implementation gets a bit ropey because the component ends up calling controller methods against the Blazor Server instance, and I'm sure I've seen Microsoft say that's bad but I don't recall where...

I'd really like for my IHelloWorld to be the single interface that works server side and client side. Server side, I can inject my concrete implementation, and client side I'd like to inject a Refit implementation. I tried being a bit hacky and had my Refit interface inherit from the IHelloWorld and marked each method as new with the appropriate attributes to make Refit work...

```csharp
public interface IHelloWorldClient : IHelloWorld
{
  [Get("/api/HelloWorld/HelloWorld"])
  new Task<string> GetHelloWorld();
}
```

... and then tried to use this in the DI container...

```csharp
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHelloWorld,IHelloWorldClient>();
```

... but for obvious reasons this fails at runtime as IHelloWorldClient can't be instantiated. When I use Refit, a proxy is automatically generated which implements this interface but I've no idea how to instantiate this myself.

Is it possible to use a very similar approach to get IHelloWorld to work server side and client side, or do I need to write a client side class that implements IHelloWorld and then calls to an injected IHelloWorldClient instead? I'm trying to avoid this as it's a *lot* of repetition.

Comment: I think this needs more focus. There is a lot of explanation here, but at the end of the day I think you start out by saying that you want on implementation on the blazor server side (access to external data) and a different implementation on the client side (access only to the blazor server side) ... so the answer to your question is YES you need to write a client side implementation which will not be the same as the server side code ...

Comment: ... although I'm not sure you need two implementions of the *same* interface - you just need the server to be able to do one thing (get data from external source) and the client to to another (get data from the server). The server can implement IGetDataFromExternalSource and the client can implement IGetDataFromTheServer - in other words, its up to you how you decide to organize your classes, interfaces, services, etc.

Comment: @topsail sadly if they're two different interfaces, then I need to write two different versions of the same Razor component. I was hoping that by having a single interface and two implementations, I wouldn't have to duplicate Razor classes.

I was planning to use the Refit client and controllers from Blazor Server to effectively proxy requests (though not in the HTTP sense) from the WASM app to the Service layer. My esoteric example might not have conveyed that well enough, so I'll look to update it :)

Comment: It would seem to me that Refit is the issue preventing you from building a clean implementation.   So why not just create a `IHelloWorld` WASM implementation that injects the IHttpClientFactory, gets a client and makes the API call.

Comment: You also don't need to inject the service directly into the component.  You can inject `IServiceProvider` and then try to get the services manually.  You can check which service is registered and use it.